# What's up with the [worldbuilding-process] tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

It seems like [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process) is just tacked on questions that it doesn't belong on.  Some of these are just poor questions entirely, but many seem to be good worldbuilding questions about processes in their world.  Not questions about the process of worldbuilding.  I scrolled through the list back to 2019, and found only 6 questions that used the tag correctly.

Is there something we can do about this?

Answer (score 6):

The standard process of editing: remove the tag, leave a comment so that OP and others can see what happened.

Comment: Yup. In fact, isn't there a badge awarded to motivate people to edit question tags?

Answer (score 6):

This is a long-standing issue on the site. [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process) has long been misused, despite having what I've always though of as a well-written and explicit tag wiki and tag excerpt. I'd argue that at some point (honestly, years ago) we should do a comprehensive survey of the questions that use the tag and edit it off of the ones that use it incorrectly. Other sites have had tag blitzes of this sort, mostly on weekends, holidays or other times with low site activity, so the front page is cluttered up by the rapid edits. If folks are interested in doing that, maybe we can organize an effort like this. It would take a lot of coordination and cooperation - and it shouldn't just be one or two people doing it - but it's doable.

Going forward, we also may want to talk about *why* the [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process) tag is so often incorrectly used and what we can do to prevent further misuse in the future.